# I make this for balancing parenthesis of equation but i think it is wrong check and correct it

Tags: c

```
int main(){
char i,input[30],close,open;
for(i=0;i<='.';i++){
  printf("enter equation");
  scanf("%c",input[i]);
  if(input[i]=='(')
    input++;
  input[i]=open;
  else if(input[i]==')')
    input[i]--;
  input[i]=close;
  else if(open[i]==close[i])
  {
    printf("parenthesis are balance");
  }
  else
    printf("parenthesis are not balance");
  }

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong about it?  Does it produce wrong results?

Comment: The input buffer is rather small. You might want to make it bigger or add a size check to prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: Will this even compile? If you have multiple lines of code you want in an "if" block you need to surround them with { }.

Comment: @muhammadlodhi : A much improved question from your last : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648130/please-help-me-for-this-program-of-parenthesis-and-operation-balanced-closed

Answer (score 4):

If you'd use indentation on your code you could spot the problems a lot easier:

```
int main()
{
    char i,input[30],close,open;
    for(i=0;i<='.';i++) // why i <= '.'? maybe you mean int i and input[i] != '.'...
    {
        printf("enter equation");
        scanf("%c",input[i]); // you need &input[i]. In fact, I think what you need is scanf("%s", input); but outside of this for loop...
        if(input[i]=='(')
            input++; // Do you mean input[i]++?
        input[i]=open; // this isn't inside the if condition. Use brackets if you want it to be
        else if(input[i]==')') // won't compile because there's no matching if
            input[i]--;
        input[i]=close; // not inside the else. Also, what is close and open? You don't initialize them
        else if(open[i]==close[i]) // open and close are not arrays. You can't use them like this
        {
            printf("paranthesis are balance");
        }
        else
            printf("paranthesis are not balance");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

There's a lot wrong. I suggest reading a tutorial. [This one](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/C/CatalogC.htm), for example. You can google for more with "C tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

The technique I'd use is to go through the input, keeping a counter of parentheses.  For each '(', increment the counter.  For each ')', decrement the counter and check if it's negative (to spot things like "())(()", which has the same number of left and right parens, but aren't balanced).  If the counter goes negative at any point, the parens are unbalanced, otherwise they're balanced if the counter is zero at the end.

Frankly, I completely fail to understand what you're trying to accomplish with the above code, and I've got a lot of experience at reading student C code, so all I can give you is algorithmic advice.